# Calculating the probability of winning at least $128$ dollars in a lottery St. Petersburg Paradox

Tags: probability, probability-theory

**The St. Petersburg Paradox:**

Here is a lottery: a fair coin is flipped repeatedly until it produces "heads." If the first occurrence of heads is on the $nth$ toss, you are paid $2^{n-1}$. So for instance, if heads appears on the first toss, you are paid $1$ dollar; if heads appears for the first time on the second toss, you are paid $2$ dollars, and so on.

Generally, the paradox is that a person would not be willing to pay an infinite amount of money to play such a lottery, and the estimates are between $10$-$20$ dollars only.

My question is that how do I calculate the probability of winning at least $128$ dollars?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To win at least 128 dollars, you need a sequence of 7 tails, so the probability is $ \frac{1}{2^7}=\frac{1}{128}$

Comment: Thought of it as well but the "at least" thing confused me.

Comment: This gives the probability of winning exactly 128 dollars-right? For atleast 128 dollars, you have to sum the series $1/2^k$ from $k=7$ to $\infty$.

Comment: @voldemort Not exactly.  This gives the probability of winning _at least_ $\$128$, because nothing is said about anything *but* the first 7 coin flips.  The probability of winning _exactly_ $\$128$ is actually 50% smaller; it takes a precise sequence of seven tails followed by a head, so the probability is $2^{-8}$.  Another way of calculating the probability of winning at least $\$128$, in fact, is by calculating the probability of flipping exactly seven tails followed by a head, then eight tails, etc: $2^{-8}+2^{-9}+2^{-10}+\ldots$.  Can you convince yourself that this is just $2^{-7}$?

Comment: @voldemort here's an alternative way to think about it. The probability $\frac{1}{128}$ gives you a sequence $TTTTTTT...$, with the dots being all possibilities. So the probability could also be written as $(\frac{1}{128})(1)$

Comment: Oh yes. I see it now :). Thanks.