# Playing the St. Petersburg Lottery until I lose everything

Tags: probability, probability-theory

This question continues the following question: [Calculating the probability of winning at least $128$ dollars in a lottery St. Petersburg Paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690538/calculating-the-probability-of-winning-at-least-128-dollars-in-a-lottery-st-p)

Here is a lottery: A fair coin is flipped repeatedly until it produces "heads." If the first occurrence of heads is on the $n$th toss, you are paid $2^{n−1}$. So for instance, if heads appears on the first toss, you are paid 1 dollar; if heads appears for the first time on the second toss, you are paid 2 dollars, and so on.

Say the cost of entering the lottery is 10 dollars and I start with 100 dollars. I'll play the lottery again and again until I have more than 10 dollars to play the game.

Now my question is, what is the probability that I can go on playing the game?

Example: Say during the first game, I get a heads on the first toss then I'll be left with 91(=100-10+1) dollars. I'll play the game again by paying 10 dollars and this time I may get a heads on the 7 toss and now I'll have 145(=91-10+64) dollars and so on.

Edit: Or Is it possible to find the probability of surviving the nth round given that I have survived all the previous rounds??

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? You can always play again after one game. Do you want to know the expected number of games you can play until you run out of money?

Comment: @Zach Gershkoff: I think the point is that you keep playing new rounds unless and until your bankroll is under $\$10$, and that there is a probability that you never stop, with the question being what is that probability.

Comment: @ZachGershkoff: Exactly as Henry says...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28076/139123 (and its answers) might be of interest.

Answer (score 3):

I do not see an easy approach, so I tried a simulation in R using the following code, which sees whether you lose in the first million games, repeated $100000$ times:

```
set.seed(2015)
subgames   <- 10
supergames <- 100000 # maximum games is supergames*subgames
cases      <- 100000 
gain     <- function(x, y=10){ ifelse(y<10, y, y + 2^-ceiling(log(x,2)) -10) }
position <- matrix(rep(NA,(subgames+1) * cases), nrow=cases)
position[, 1] <- 100 # start with 100
for (r in 1:supergames){
    subcases <- nrow(position)
    udata <- matrix( runif(subgames * subcases ), nrow=subcases )
    for (n in 1:subgames ){ position[, n+1] <- gain(udata[,n], position[,n]) } 
    position[, 1] <- position[, subgames+1]     # ready to restart 
    position <- position[position[,1] >= 10, ] # remove lost games
    }
nrow(position)/cases
```

It produced the result `0.00021`, suggesting that the simulation lost $99979$ times but failed to lose $21$ times.  Of those $21$ cases, after a million games the surviving bankrolls were in the range $68183$ to $17492689$ in this particular simulation, so there was a net average gain.

Obviously there is uncertainty associated with any simulation and there may be further losses as the number of games increases further, but this suggests the probability of not losing overall is extremely small. About $82\%$ of losses seemed to have happened in the first twenty games and about $97\%$ of losses in the first hundred games, so the unbounded potential gains do not often offset the price of playing repeated games.

Comment: Thank you Henry for the results... But I was thinking more like expressing the probability as a function of the what the Gambler initially starts with and the cost per game.. As far as my thought goes, the (numerical) answer can be got by applying Markov chain with infinite number of states.. Can anyone tell me how to compute the probability (or the Expectation) in a Markov chain with infinite number of states??

Comment: The expected bankroll after any finite number of games (including just $1$) is infinite.  But that does not answer the question of whether the probability of surviving an infinite number of games is zero or not.

Comment: Probability of survival is larger than $0$ as long as the player can afford the first ticket since $\liminf \frac{S_n}{\frac 1 2 n\log_2 n}=1$ a.s. Basically, if one survives $2^{2c(1+1)}$ games, one is very likely to survive afterwards as at this point typical winnings are twice the cost to run this long (with a possible upside) - so the portfilio becomes self-sustaining w.h.p. This would require runs of at least $10^{12}$ games to correctly estimate probability of ruin for $c=10$.

Comment: A great approximation for the probability of ruin is $P(ruin)\approx \exp(-1.08\cdot 2X/2^{2c})\approx 0.99979$ which fully agrees with your simulation.

Answer (score 2):

Let $P_n$ be the probability of losing (not indefinitely having enough money to play) if you start with $n$ dollars. Now, we can observe that the probabilities don't change after one step, except it's now distributed over the possible values of $n$. As such, we can express that, for $n\geq 10$,
$$
P_n = \frac{P_{n-9}}2 + \frac{P_{n-8}}4 + \frac{P_{n-6}}8 + \cdots + \frac{P_{n-10+2^k}}{2^{k+1}} + \cdots
$$
which states our requirement that the limit to infinity doesn't change. We also have that $P_n=1$ for $n<10$.

Investigations of this system using Octave, by constructing the matrix system for this, while taking $P_n=0$ for $n>n_{max}$ (this creates an $(n_{max}-9)\times(n_{max}-9)$ matrix system), produce an interesting result:

As we increase $n_{max}$, $P_n$ gets larger for each $n$... in a way that suggests that they are tending to 1. That is, it is looking as though, for any finite $n$, the final result will actually be $P_n=1$, meaning that, given enough time, the player will run out of money at some point. For instance, for  $n_{max}=5009$, we get $P_{100}\approx 0.9960939$. For $n_{max}=10009$, we get $P_{100}\approx 0.9977098$. Here are the probability curves that result for $n_{max}$ = 2509, 5009, and 10009 (note: x coordinate is shifted by 9, so the first curve runs from 1 to 2500 rather than 10 to 2509):

[image: Probabilities P_n]

Note that these effectively show the probability of losing if the player has $n$ dollars at the start and the house has $n_{max}-n$ dollars that they can give - that is, if the player wins enough to reach $n_{max}$, then they have cleaned out the house's bank, and have "won", while if the player drops below 10 dollars, they have "lost". Reminder: the $P_n$ shown in the graph shows the probability of losing.

Comment: $P_n<1$ for $n\ge c$ since $\liminf \frac{S_n}{n\log n}=1$ - that is at every starting level, if you survive long enough ($\gg 2^c$ rounds), you are likely to continue playing forever. For starting capital of $100$ this probability is tiny, but not zero. Numerical explorations for fat-tailed variables are notoriously unreliable - especially for $\alpha=1$.

Answer (score 1):

*Note:* The following argument makes it *plausible* that the *probability* to loose the game tends to zero in the long run.

We show, that this behaviour is valid independent of the *cost* of a game, as long as it is constant and we argue, that it is also valid independent of the *seed money*.

> **Intro:** The *St. Petersburg Paradox* is a famous game dealing with gambler ruin sequences. One important paper regarding this game is *[Note on the law of large numbers and fair games](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177731094)* by W. Feller from $1937$.
>
> Another interesting paper *[On Steinhaus' resolution of the St. Petersburg Paradox](http://www.math.uni.wroc.pl/~pms/files/14.2/Article/14.2.1.pdf)* by S. Szörgö and G. Simmons elaborates the so-called *Steinhaus sequences*. These sequences, introduced $1949$ by *Hugo Steinhaus*  show *with probability $1$* the same empirical distribution function as the sequences coming from the St. Petersburg Paradox.
>
> The essential of the paradox is the *non-existence of a finite expectation value* and most of the papers address the problem how could the game adopted to change it into a *fair game*.

**Critical sequences:** OP's question does not care about these aspects. Here we are interested only in the probability of winning the game in the long run. Let's look at a sequence of heads and tails

\begin{align*}
HH\color{blue}{T}HHHH\color{blue}{T}\color{blue}{T}\color{blue}{T}H\color{blue}{T}H\color{blue}{T}\ldots\tag{1}
\end{align*}

The sequence in (1) starts with the $6$ consecutive games

\begin{align*}
HH\color{blue}{T},HHH\color{blue}{T},\color{blue}{T},\color{blue}{T},H\color{blue}{T},H\color{blue}{T},\ldots
\end{align*}

Whenever the coin shows $H$, the gain is doubled until the first time $T$ occurs, ending this instance of the game. If $c_0$ is the cost for each instance we get for

$$H^nT\qquad \text{ a gain of} \qquad 2^{n}-c_0 \qquad\qquad n\geq 0$$

Let's look at some characteristic aspects. We observe that $c_0$ compensates roughly $[\log_2(c_0)]$ wins. In OPs example $c_0=10$ and so whenever a game is of the form $T,HT,HHT$ or $HHHT$, ie. a game with no more than $[\log_2(c_0)]$ $H$'s we have a loss (or no win in case $c_0=2^k$). Let's call those sequences which *decrease* the current score **critical sequences**.

> We observe that one characteristic to determine the result of the game is *the distribution of critical sequences* in the long run of the game.
>
> The higher the value $c_0$, the more critical sequences are possible within a game and the question is, do they contribute a considerable amount among *all pathes*, so that the probability for a loss in the long-run is greater zero.

We also note, that at the time we do *not adress* the seed money $m_0$. In OP's example $m_0=100$, but let's ignore it for the moment and assume $m_0=0$.

> **Lattice Pathes:**
>
> We can model the game using **lattice pathes**. We thereby associate a lattice path to a sequence of form (1) consisting of ascending steps $a$ for each *H* in $(1,1)$ direction and descending steps $b$ for each *T* in $(1,-1)$ direction.

We now analyse lattice pathes with respect to *critical sequences*.

Let

$$SEQ(a)=\{\varepsilon,a,aa,aaa,\ldots\}$$

denote all pathes containing only a's with length $\geq 0$. A path with length zero is denoted with $\varepsilon$. The corresponding generating function is
$$(az)^0+(az)^1+(az)^2+\ldots=
\frac{1}{1-az},$$
 with the exponent of $z^n$ marking the length $n$ of a path of $a$'s and the coefficient of $(az)^n$ marking the *number* of pathes of length $n$.

Let $SEQ^{\geq k}(a)$ be the set of all pathes of $a$'s with length $\geq k$. The generating function for $SEQ^{\geq k}(a)$ is $\frac{(az)^k}{1-az}$.

> We can now describe the sequences in (1) as *all those pathes* which can be build as concatenation of one or more parts of the form
>
> $$SEQ(a)b=\{b,ab,aab,aaab,\ldots\}\qquad\longleftrightarrow\qquad G(z)=\frac{bz}{1-az}$$
>
> This leads to the formal description
>
> $$SEQ^{\geq 1}(SEQ(a)b)$$ with the generating function
>
> \begin{align*}
> H(z)&=\frac{G(z)}{1-G(z)}=\frac{\frac{bz}{1-az}}{1-\frac{bz}{1-az}}
> =\frac{bz}{1-(a+b)z}\\
> \\
> &=bz\sum_{n\geq 0}(a+b)^nz^n\\
> &=\sum_{n\geq 0}\sum_{j=0}^n\binom{n}{j}a^jb^{n-j+1}z^{n+1}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> **Conclusion:** In case $c_0=10$, meaning the cost of one instance of a game is $10$, the critical pathes are $b,ab,aab$ and $aaab$. The *distribution of these critical pathes* within *all* $2^n$ pathes of length $n+1$ and ending with $b$ is according to (2)
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\binom{n}{3}}{2^n}=\frac{P(n)}{2^n}
> \end{align*}
>   with $P(n)$ a polynomial of degree $3$.
>
> We observe that in the long run for *all* values $c_0$ the number of critical pathes within a game of length $n$ correlates to a polynomial $P(n)$ of degree $[\log_2(c_0)]$ and since
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{P(n)}{2^n}=0\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>   the probability to loose the St. Peterburg game in the long run also seems to tend to zero.

**Note:**

- The **seed money $m_0$** has presumably only influence with respect to the *length* of the games. The greater the seed, the greater the chance for a longer game. But it also seems that this has *no impact* for the resulting probability when considering the wins and losses of all pathes of length $n$ with $n$ going to infinity. The *polynomial increase* of the critical pathes versus the *exponential increase* of *all pathes* will always tend to a winning probability of $1$ in the long run.

*Note:* The notation and the formal description of pathes corresponds to an example in I.1.4 in  *P. Flajolet's* and *R. Sedgewicks* [Analytic Combinatorics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521898064)

Comment: This can't be correct. Clearly seed money negatively affects probability of losing since if you start with less than entrance price, you already lost. You basically shown that with infinite wealth with probability 1 you eventually get ahead - which follows from SLLN.

Answer (score 0):

If you play 8 games, you expect to be down \$9 in 4, \$8 in 2 and \$6 in 1 with the last game still undecided. So you should expect to be down \$60. If you play another 8 games, you will be -\$9 $* 8$, -\$8 $* 4$, -\$6 $* 2$ and down another \$2, with a minor chance of winning \$2. So down \$116, and so game over. You could win, but the probability of you winning is only $1/16$, so for every 16 plays, you are down roughly \$116.

You might think you could easily win \$1014, but it would take approxiamately 2048 attempts, costing you \$20480.

I wrote a similar game once, but in this one the odds are equal:
http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/GameOfDice/